# Error on different ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting this error when I do `rails s`

`Your Ruby version is 2.1.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.1`

But when I do `ruby - v`
I get `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]`

Searched around, I did do `bundle install` nothing.  Any other solution?

Comment: what ruby version manager do you use? rvm or rbenv

Comment: run `which bundle` and `which ruby`, they may give you an idea of what is happening and if rbenv or rvm is being used.  Also check for a hidden file called .ruby-version in the home directory of your app.

Comment: @kristianp where can i find it? I do not see if in the directory under my app.

Comment: I'm using rvm @WilliamHerry

Comment: @JamAndJammies Try running  `rvm use ruby 2.2.1` and then `bundle install` and then run `rails s`. I think rvm is taking ruby version as 2.1.5 in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a gemset for ruby 2.2.1

- $ rvm use ruby 2.2.1
- $ rvm gemset create ruby221railsxxx
- $ rvm gemset use ruby221railsxxx
- $ bundle install

This might solve your problem.